# Selecting Distinct Based on a Nested Object Realm

Tags: android, realm

I have the following relationship between Contract, Farmer and Crop

Crop:

```
public class Crop extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    public String publicId;
    public String cropName;
}
```

Contract:

```
public class Contract extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    public String internalId;
    public Crop crop;
    public Farmer farmer;
}
```

I want to select distinct crops from a all contracts belonging to a farmer. How can I archive this?

Answer (score 0):

Realm 3.5.0+:

```
public class Crop extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    public String publicId;
    public String cropName;

    @LinkingObjects("contract") 
    public final RealmResults<Contract> cropOf = null;
}
```

Then

```
realm.where(Crop.class)
          .equalTo("cropOf.farmer.farmerId", farmerId) 
          .distinct("cropName");
```